# Java EE applications and WET solutions

Tags: entity, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I have to develop one big Java EE 6 application on JBoss AS 7. The application is big and must be split in modules (it's a request).

To maintain modularity I organize it into modules like .war and .jar. A couple, .war + .jar, corresponds to an application module. Some of the .jars have to share the same entities.

Now I must duplicate entities to maintain modularity or it's better to create a .jar to share among the other jars as a lib? Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one jar file and have the individual applications pull it into their classpath using Maven.